# Mac OS X, pip: specify compiler for packages containing C libraries

Tags: python, c, osx-lion, pip, pypi

I am having some trouble with compiling mapscript (is a package from pypi containing C code) with the default clang compiler using pip.

Here's my attempt:-

```
$ sudo pip install mapscript
Password:
Downloading/unpacking mapscript
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mapscript

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mapscript)
Installing collected packages: mapscript
  Running setup.py install for mapscript

    building '_mapscript' extension
    /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -fPIC -Wall -DNEED_NONBLOCKING_STDERR -DHAVE_VSNPRINTF -DNEED_STRRSTR -DNEED_NONBLOCKING_STDERR -DUSE_WMS_SVR -DUSE_GDAL -DUSE_OGR -DUSE_PROJ -DUSE_EPPL -DUSE_GD_GIF -DUSE_GD_PNG -DUSE_GD_JPEG -DUSE_GD_WBMP -DUSE_GD_FT -DGD_HAS_FTEX_XSHOW -DGD_HAS_GDIMAGEGIFPTR -DGD_HAS_GETBITMAPFONTS -DUSE_ICONV -DUSE_ZLIB -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -DHAVE_VSNPRINTF -DNEED_STRRSTR -DNEED_NONBLOCKING_STDERR -DUSE_WMS_SVR -DUSE_GDAL -DUSE_OGR -DUSE_PROJ -DUSE_EPPL -DUSE_GD_GIF -DUSE_GD_PNG -DUSE_GD_JPEG -DUSE_GD_WBMP -DUSE_GD_FT -DGD_HAS_FTEX_XSHOW -DGD_HAS_GDIMAGEGIFPTR -DGD_HAS_GETBITMAPFONTS -DUSE_ICONV -DUSE_ZLIB -DHAVE_VSNPRINTF -DNEED_STRRSTR -DNEED_NONBLOCKING_STDERR -DUSE_WMS_SVR -DUSE_GDAL -DUSE_OGR -DUSE_PROJ -DUSE_EPPL -DUSE_GD_GIF -DUSE_GD_PNG -DUSE_GD_JPEG -DUSE_GD_WBMP -DUSE_GD_FT -DGD_HAS_FTEX_XSHOW -DGD_HAS_GDIMAGEGIFPTR -DGD_HAS_GETBITMAPFONTS -DUSE_ICONV -DUSE_ZLIB -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c mapscript_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/mapscript_wrap.o
    mapscript_wrap.c:2564:23: error: mapserver.h: No such file or directory
    mapscript_wrap.c:2565:25: error: maptemplate.h: No such file or directory
    mapscript_wrap.c:2566:23: error: mapogcsld.h: No such file or directory
...
mapscript_wrap.c:45472: error: 'MS_DEBUGLEVEL_VV' undeclared (first use in this function)

mapscript_wrap.c:45473: error: 'MS_DEBUGLEVEL_VVV' undeclared (first use in this function)

mapscript_wrap.c:45476: error: 'MS_GET_REQUEST' undeclared (first use in this function)

mapscript_wrap.c:45477: error: 'MS_POST_REQUEST' undeclared (first use in this function)

error: command '/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/calvin/build/mapscript/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-GYwtAz-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/calvin/.pip/pip.log
```

The gcc-apple-4.2 version is

```
$ gcc-apple-4.2 --version
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-apple-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How do I try installing mapscript with another compiler?  Is there a way to explicitly specify a specific compiler that pip will call upon when compiling the C code in a pypi package?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. Is Python on Lion broken?

Comment: Hi @KyleWpppd, after some digging around, I learnt that mapscript's C-extension by default compiles using the same compiler which I compiled Python 2.7 (via Macports) with.

Since I used gcc-apple-4.2 for compiling my Python 2.7 via MacPorts, the same compiler will be used when compiling mapscript.

In order to solve this problem, I had to make sure that I compile MapServer 6.0.1 correctly first (and MapServer 6.0.1 is not available on MacPorts - the copy on MacPorts is severely outdated). Thereafter, I did "sudo python setup.py build" to install mapscript system-wide.

Comment: I'm also having the same trouble on OS X 10.8.2 -- I've installed mapserver with --devel via Mac HomeBrew, but pip install mapscript fails for a very similar reason. It can't find mapserver.h anywhere.

Answer (score 25):

Setting the CC environment variable seems to work, e.g.:

> env CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 pip install pyOpenSSL

Comment: This does not address the question nor the problem. The problem clearly shows that the build process uns able to find required header files. mapserver.h is the first. --JamesMills

Comment: The question was "How do I try installing mapscript with another compiler?" I believe this answer very specifically addresses that.